# How to confirm SharePoint and Workflow Manager is configured correctly?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow

http://sharepointdeal.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/register-spworkflowservice-failed-to-query-the-oauth-s2s-metadata-error/

looking at the SharePoint logs – the error details are

```
Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InvalidRequestException: Failed to query the OAuth S2S metadata endpoint at URI ‘http://xxxx/_layouts/15/metadata/json/1&#8242;. Error details: ‘An error occurred while sending the request.’. HTTP headers received from the server – ActivityId: 1b2624e2-42a0-4a93-8c93-2ada0630967c. NodeId: xxxx. Scope: /SharePoint. Client ActivityId : 487d86fd-c961-4d8c-aab2-47269989b292. —> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.     at
```

Basically, it is trying to connect to the SharePoint URL endpoint (http://xxxx/_layouts/15/metadata/json/1 . In my case, the SharePoint URL (which has host header) was not accessible from Workflow Manager server (as I have not published the URL in DNS). I added the SharePoint URL to the Workflow manager server host file and can access the SharePoint URL.

Now the Register-SPWorkflowservice command runs without issue.

The key here is that make sure that both SharePoint and workflow host URLs are accessible from the SharePoint / Workflow Manager server.

My question is:

> HOW should I make sure that both SharePoint and workflow host URLs are
>   accessible from the SharePoint / Workflow Manager server?

Comment: Are you asking how to set it up or how to verify that you have set it up correctly?

Comment: The answer is "how to verify that you have set it up correctly"

Answer (score 1):

Open SharePoint Designer 2013 and connect to any site in the farm. In the Navigation panel choose Workflows and create a new workflow. If you can drop down the Platform Type combo box and choose SharePoint 2013 Workflow, you are successful. If it only displays 2010 you are not.